# How can I make constraints that the label does not exceed the center of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

[image: How to make constraints for this label to start from left and not exceed the center of the view]

I tried a lot but i am not sure how i can make it right without it exceeding the half of screen

Talking about the upper label at right

Comment: So you want the label to be pinned to the top and right?

Comment: @aheze yes and not exceed half of screen

Comment: "not exceed half of screen" what should the label do if it goes over half the screen? Should it shrink?

Comment: @aheze yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements for the label are:

1. Pin to top and right
2. Never cross the horizontal center of the screen

The constraints that you need are:

1. Top and trailing
2. Proportional width to superview, with equal-or-less-than 0.5 multiplier

[image: Image of the constraints]

Here's how you add them:

1. Select your label
2. Press the constraints button, then add the top and right constraints

[image: Add the top and right constraints in popup]

3. Right-click and hold on the label, then drag to the superview (the screen)

[image: Blue line connecting label and superview]

4. Release, then choose <kbd>Equal Widths</kbd>
5. In the size inspector, find the constraint that was just added. Press <kbd>Edit</kbd>, then set the "Constant" to `<=` and the "Multiplier" to `0.5`.

[image: Configuring popup after selecting the constraint]

That's it!

| 400 width superview | 200 width | 100 width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Label at right] | [image: Label still at right, still free space to the left] | [image: Label at right, but limited to half of the superview's width] |